# How to define the Clothoid Constant in Clothodial Arc ( Spiral Curve)?

Tags: civil-engineering, rail, highway-engineering

Referring to the  document here on [IfcClothoidalArcSegment2D](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/mvd/IFC4x1/Alignment/1.0/html/schema/ifcgeometryresource/lexical/ifcclothoidalarcsegment2d.htm), we have `ClothoidConstant`, which is defined as

> The constant $A$ (not $A^2$), that determines the rate of curvature
>   change along the clothoid.

I wonder what it actually is?

From the wiki page about [Euler Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral#Symbols), I found a symbol $a$, which is calculated to be

$a={1\over \sqrt{2R_cs_o}} $

It has the same dimension of the above `ClothoidConstant`, $A$.

Are they actually the same? If not, how should the `ClothoidConstant` be defined?

Comment: It looks like semantics.  I can write  "K is proportional to the square of A" and then still say that "A determines the [something] of K" .  At most you'd be off by a factor of 2.